# How come file.readline() works, yet open('name of file', 'r').readline() does not?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, readline

I have just solved a dilemma that has cost me at least a good 3 hours of my life:

```
>>> open('foo.py','r')
>>> open('foo.py','r').readline()
>>> ''
```

I tried various combinations, and to no avail, and of course I asked uncle Google

This as you know howewer, does work

```
>>> bar=open('foo.py','r')
>>> bar.readline()
>>> 'Crap'
>>> bar.readline()
>>> 'More crap'
>>> bar.readline()
>>> 'Even MORE crap'
>>> bar.readline()
>>> 'End of crap'
```

So, I always thought that the value assigned to a variable is just that. As simple as this seems
it just can't be, otherwise the code would work either way.

Instead of asking for a direct answer, does anyone have any materials I could go over, probably not
a wiki page, as that's a bit too advanced, but an article of sorts.

Comment: In your first example i see readline instead of readline()

Comment: You are not *calling* the method in your first sample. If you are repeatedly using `open('foo.py','r').readline()` then you'd repeatedly *reopen* the file and read the first line.

Comment: Ironically the code you've posted in title is correct: `open('name of file', 'r').readline()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `readline()` on a file object will read from the file until it finds a linebreak and return whatever it has read. During that process, the internal pointer will be positioned on the next line, so another call of `readline()` will read the *next* line, until the end of the file is found.

The internal pointer is of course only kept if you keep referring to the same file object. Calling `open()` will give you such a file object, but calling `open()` again will just give you another independent file object.

So doing `open(…).readline()` twice will just open the file, read the first line, and throw away the file object then—twice. The second `readline()` call will refer to a new file object which of course does not share the pointer from the first one.

So if you want to read through the full file, you should only use *one* file object and call `readline()` repeatedly on that one.

Finally note that *calling* a method actually means adding parentheses at the end. Otherwise, you will just refer to the method without actually calling it.

Comment: Sheers mate, this is pretty much the only constructive comment here. Though independent  of that this is still a top notch answer.


So, does assignment the file object to a variable create a new object? I thought this simply Aliasis the variable w/ the object?

Comment: Calling `open()` will create a new file object. You can save that to variables or discard it, that doesn’t really matter. If you call `open()` again, you get a new file object with a fresh state (starting at the first character).

Answer (score 2):

In the first instance you aren't calling the function!

```
open('foo.py','r').readline
```

If you try it like this:

```
open('foo.py','r').readline()
```

You should see behaviour you expected.